# Definite ariticle before "sunlight" and "air"?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Do you put the definite article "the" before "air" and "sunlight"? I know it mostly depends on context, so I have come up with example sentences.

Let's say I want to say these following sentences:

***Sunlight*** is very strong in my country.

*Strong **sunlight** isn't good for your skin.*

***The air*** is very fresh today.

*Canada boasts fresh **air**.*

Comment: All four sentences are correct and idiomatic.

Comment: It wouldn't be so if I say "The sunlight is very strong in my country" and "The strong sunlight isn't good for your skin" right? Notice the definitive articles.

Comment: isn't this question better suited for English language learners ? https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The zero article is used when speaking *generally*. E.g. *Strong sunlight is never good for your skin* vs *The strong sunlight today isn't good for your skin*.

The definitive article is used for a *specific* case. Same goes for your third example, *Today's air isn't very fresh*. It's talking about air on a specific moment.

Comment: You say "The definitive article is used for a specific case," but then you note that "Today's air is definite" specific ... but it doesn't use the definite article. Isn't this contradictory?

Answer (score 0):

> Sunlight is very strong in my country.

I would say "The sunlight is very strong in my country" works just as well, or maybe even a bit better.

> Strong sunlight isn't good for your skin.

This is correct; "The strong sunlight..." would be wrong here.

> The air is very fresh today.

This is correct; "Air..." would be wrong here.

> Canada boasts fresh air.

This is correct; "...the fresh air" would be wrong here.